# Retrieving selected users and storing them into another table

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I would like to get all entries from a database table with a given value (example: `UserType` value is 1).

What I want to happen is to get all users with `1` as a `UserType` and then store it which will then be used in an insert statement into another table.

The processed users should be inserted into another table using their `UserID`. and I am thinking of selecting first the the users and then using loops to input them into the table but I do not know how.

Here's the sample code that I will be using in inserting the users into another table.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (@MessageTo, @Subject)";

com.Parameters.Add("@MessageTo", SqlDbType.Int);
com.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

com.Parameters[0].Value =  //this is where the userIDs of the users selected should be entered
com.Parameters[1].Value = "test";

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this would be a 3-4 line answer with [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework). It's great and does all the things. When you get really good at making your own sql commands, give that a shot.

So, let's assume that you have made your code in this fashion (pseudo code):

```
public class User // a class for holding details about a user
{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    //others
}

// a list holding the users you want to insert
List<User> usersToInsert = new List<User>();

// get the users in some way
usersToInsert = TheSelectStatementToGetUsersToInsert();
```

Now you need to one-by-one insert those users into the database. Use a `foreach` loop on `usersToInsert`.

```
foreach (var user in usersToInsert)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (@MessageTo, @Subject)";

    com.Parameters.Add("@MessageTo", SqlDbType.Int);
    com.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    // this is where you use the iterator variable
    com.Parameters[0].Value = user.UserID;
    com.Parameters[1].Value = "test";

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```

It is also good to look into [having `using` statements](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx) for your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` variables. They will always close the connection so you don't have to remember to.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. I just would like to clarify where should I put the SELECT statement to get all those users? is it going to be under TheSelectStatementToGetUsersToInsert(); like i'm going to create new method private void TheSelectStatementToGetUsersToInsert(); and then use it in usersToInsert?

Comment: Yes, the `select` statement to get users would go in that "area". I just used a method as an example. You could just paste that code in and assign the results to the list variable. Though I would suggest making a method to prevent mile-long methods.

Comment: @CharlesTan, and if you did make a method, it would be `private List<User> SomeMethodName()`, because you want to return a list of `Users`.

Comment: Alright, I consolidated all the codes to be used. Could you please check if this is correct? Here's the link. http://pastie.org/8487174